# Where will the World First Lego League be held in 2015?

Tags: lego-group, fll

Every year [First Lego League (FLL)](http://www.firstlegoleague.org/) is held in 3 different countries. I know that the world festival will be held in St. Louis, but where will the other two be?

Last year it was held in Germany and Canada.

Comment: Sorry there is no tag for FLL so I chose the lego group because its the closest to my question, if someone can create a tag for FLL that will be great.

Comment: I fear that this is likely to be considered "too localised" as it's only going to be a valid question for the next few months :(

Comment: Will be repeated every year right?

Comment: Yes, but this question is specifically asking about 2015 - you've already pointed out that it was in different locations last year.

Comment: Hmm, just remembered that we [removed Too Localised last year](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185102/33051). This may well be closed as Off Topic at some future point when it's no longer relevant though.

Answer (score 3):

The FLL World Festival is going to be held in St. Louis, MO, USA, on April 22-25, 2015 (http://www.firstlegoleague.org/event/worldfestival).  This is the only official championship event held by the FLL.

Before the World Festival, various qualifying events are held all over the world.  You can learn more about those events by searching on this page: http://www3.usfirst.org/whats-going-on

Unofficially, FLL partners hold Open Championships around the world.  These events generally take place in the United States (in addition to the official World Festival), Canada, Asia, and Europe.  For more information, visit this Wikipedia page:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIRST_Lego_League_Open_Championships